# Query removes characters after a diacritic

Tags: php, diacritics

I am executing the following query from PHP

```
INSERT INTO oc_category_description SET category_id = '5', language_id = '1', name = 'Artículos ErÃ³ticos', meta_keyword = '', meta_description = '', description = ''
```

but the value is inserted into name field as 'Art'. It looks like MySQL truncates remaining characters when it see a diacritic character like í,Ã etc. I enabled the MySQL query log and it shows the query in full as above. Anybody knows where could be the problem? Thank you

**Additional Information** : The query is used in the Opencart extension I developed, which make use of Opencart method '`$this->db->query`' to execute query. But if I enter the same value through Opencart admin, the value is getting inserted perfectly.

Comment: Does the query log show the diacritics the same way when you use the Opencart admin panel? This is most likely because your extension uses a different encoding somewhere.

Comment: The issue is resolved now. I used utf8_encode to encode the SQL string